# How does ExecutorService.submit work

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand how Executor.submit(Runnable) works. Suppose we create a thread pool of size 2 using ExecutorService.

We have a class called **Runner implements Runnable**.

```
ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool(2);
for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){
  ExecutorService.submit(new Runner());
}
```

When we do new Runner() are we not creating 5 threads already?

So how does ExecutorService help in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The service uses a **queue** to store the incoming Runnable objects. As soon as a thread becomes available to do work, the service uses that thread to execute the next *Runnable* object that is due.

Runnables are **not** Threads. Your example will create two threads which make up the pool; and then the 5 Runner objects will be dispatched to one of those two threads over time.

That is all there is to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the implementation of [AbstractExecutorService](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.java/?v=source) from grepcode.

`AbstractExecutorService` is base class of [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java/?v=source) and it implements [ExecutorService](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.java/?v=source)

```
public Future<?> submit(Runnable task) {
    if (task == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    RunnableFuture<Object> ftask = newTaskFor(task, null);
    execute(ftask);
    return ftask;
}

protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Runnable runnable, T value) {
    return new FutureTask<T>(runnable, value);
}
```

`execute` implementation from `ThreadPoolExecutor`

```
 public void execute(Runnable command) {
        if (command == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        /*
         * Proceed in 3 steps:
         *
         * 1. If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, try to
         * start a new thread with the given command as its first
         * task.  The call to addWorker atomically checks runState and
         * workerCount, and so prevents false alarms that would add
         * threads when it shouldn't, by returning false.
         *
         * 2. If a task can be successfully queued, then we still need
         * to double-check whether we should have added a thread
         * (because existing ones died since last checking) or that
         * the pool shut down since entry into this method. So we
         * recheck state and if necessary roll back the enqueuing if
         * stopped, or start a new thread if there are none.
         *
         * 3. If we cannot queue task, then we try to add a new
         * thread.  If it fails, we know we are shut down or saturated
         * and so reject the task.
         */
        int c = ctl.get();
        if (workerCountOf(c) < corePoolSize) {
            if (addWorker(command, true))
                return;
            c = ctl.get();
        }
        if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.offer(command)) {
            int recheck = ctl.get();
            if (! isRunning(recheck) && remove(command))
                reject(command);
            else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0)
                addWorker(null, false);
        }
        else if (!addWorker(command, false))
            reject(command);

/**
 * Checks if a new worker can be added with respect to current
 * pool state and the given bound (either core or maximum). If so,
 * the worker count is adjusted accordingly, and, if possible, a
 * new worker is created and started running firstTask as its
 * first task. This method returns false if the pool is stopped or
 * eligible to shut down. It also returns false if the thread
 * factory fails to create a thread when asked, which requires a
 * backout of workerCount, and a recheck for termination, in case
 * the existence of this worker was holding up termination.
 *
 * @param firstTask the task the new thread should run first (or
 * null if none). Workers are created with an initial first task
 * (in method execute()) to bypass queuing when there are fewer
 * than corePoolSize threads (in which case we always start one),
 * or when the queue is full (in which case we must bypass queue).
 * Initially idle threads are usually created via
 * prestartCoreThread or to replace other dying workers.
 *
 * @param core if true use corePoolSize as bound, else
 * maximumPoolSize. (A boolean indicator is used here rather than a
 * value to ensure reads of fresh values after checking other pool
 * state).
 * @return true if successful
 */

 private boolean addWorker(Runnable firstTask, boolean core)
```

Check implementation of `Worker` in same class

```
/**
 * Class Worker mainly maintains interrupt control state for
 * threads running tasks, along with other minor bookkeeping.
 * This class opportunistically extends AbstractQueuedSynchronizer
 * to simplify acquiring and releasing a lock surrounding each
 * task execution.  This protects against interrupts that are
 * intended to wake up a worker thread waiting for a task from
 * instead interrupting a task being run.  We implement a simple
 * non-reentrant mutual exclusion lock rather than use ReentrantLock
 * because we do not want worker tasks to be able to reacquire the
 * lock when they invoke pool control methods like setCorePoolSize.
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

No you are creating thread pool of 2 threads, the Executor Service will wait until there is available thread in the pool to submit the next task to the available thread.